# Is possible to create htmlhelpers dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanted to create a htmlhelpers elements depending on the value of dropdown list. Here is the code:

Dropdown

```
<select id="pracownicy">

        <option value="biurowy" style="color: black">Pracownik biurowy</option>
        <option value="przewodnik" style="color: black">Przewodnik</option>
    </select>
```

and script be like:

```
 <script>
        function pracownicy() {
            var x = document.getElementById("pracownicy");

            if (x.value.equalTo("biurowy"))
            {



            }

            if (x.value.equalTo("przewodnik")) {

            }
        }


    </script>
```

Inside these script i would like to create dynamically something like this:

For biurowy value:

```
 <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And for przewodnik value:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/huz7cyws/1/) is a working example

```
function handleChange(){

    var strg="";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function(){
        strg = strg + this.value;
    });

    if (strg =="biurowy"){
        alert('adding1');
        $('#cont').append('<p>yourForm1</p>');
    } 

    if (strg =="przewodnik"){
                alert('adding2');
        $('#cont').append('<p>yourForm2</p>');
    } 


}

$('#pracownicy').change(handleChange);
```

You need to replace `<p>yourFormX</p>` with your form code.

Pay attention that I changed dropdown code slightly as follows:

```
<select id="pracownicy">
    <option value="unselected" style="color: black">Not Selected</option>
    <option value="biurowy" style="color: black">Pracownik biurowy</option>
    <option value="przewodnik" style="color: black">Przewodnik</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks it works! But can u help me how to avoid the duplicate of these forms and also how to make that each form may be display at a time?

Comment: If you are going to show one of the form at all times, then you can remove unselected option from drop down. Let's say top item in the list is biurowy. Then you can add related form in the cont section by default. When user selects the other option from the drop down, that form will be replaced with the other one. If user goes back to first option, content will be replaced with the first form again. Does this make sense to you ? =]

Comment: ye, but how can i  "replace" this forms ?

Comment: instead of $('cont').append(), you can use $('cont').html('your form'). [Examples are here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)